# Equation of having S or more identical things

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are **N letters** to be put into **F fields**. (N may be larger *or* smaller than F.) Letters can be reused. Simply, there are **N<sup>F</sup> cases**. How many of those cases are having **S or more identical** letters. (For S <= F.)

All variables are non-negative.

For example, **N = 26 letters**, **F = 5 fields**, and **S = 3 occurrences**:

```
 [ A B C D E ]      // invalid
 [ A A X X E ]      // invalid
 [ X O X O X ]      // valid
 [ K K A K K ]      // valid
 [ J J J J J ]      // valid
```

Please provide an equation, with some explanations.

PS this is **not** a question from the assignment. i believe it may be related to nCr and/or nPr. i have tried all night but still have no clues... i got bad maths afterall :-/ Solving this will help my programming a lot.

Thanks. x

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is fairly complicated, however it's easier if we assume $S> \frac{F}{2}$:

1. Choose the letter to be repeated exactly $S$ times, $N$ ways.
2. Choose the positions for that letter, ${F\choose S}$ ways.
3. Choose the other letters, $(N-1)^{F-S}$ ways.

Combining, there are $N{F\choose S}(N-1)^{F-S}$ ways to have exactly $S$ copies of a letter.  To have at least $S$ copies of a letter, we sum this as follows:$$\sum_{i=S}^FN{F\choose i}(N-1)^{F-i}$$